# Change Excel Created Date Through VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript

The created date I want to change through VBS is shown under the File tab (Excel 2010 or later) under `Related Dates`. My question is how to change Excel's interior created date and *not* the created date of the file (aka `File Properties`).

I can change Excel's interior created date with a macro:

```
ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date") = Date
```

How do you do this through VBS? Right now I have:

```
Dim objFSO, objFile
Set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\My\Path\Excel.xls")
objFile.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date") = Date
```

But this changes the created date of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do it the same way, by instantiating Excel and acting on the open workbook:

```
Dim e
Set e = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
e.Workbooks.Open "c:\my\path\excel.xls"
e.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date") = Date
e.ActiveWorkbook.Save
e.Quit
```

Comment: Okay great. This works with one file but when I do this with multiple files (I just copied and pasted the code and changed variable names), it freezes on the second file. My Application in Task Manager reads 'Microsoft Excel - Compatibility Checker'

Comment: Try setting `e.DisplayAlerts = False` before you open the workbook.

Comment: I just fixed the problem. My excel checks the compatibility of my sheets every time I save. I can change that. Thanks!